# generate stderr log file in tomcat under linux

Tags: linux, windows, tomcat, log-files

Recently installed Tomcat 7 in windows machine and its running a web application.
Under 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\logs', I could find couple of different log files out of which I am interested in the log file 'tomcat7-stderr.2016-11-22.log'.

We have a linux machine which generates the log in location '/var/log/tomcat' but only generates the log 'localhost_access_log.2016-11-22.txt'. How can I enable tomcat to generate the 'tomcat7-stderr.2016-11-22.log' error log?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

From catalina.sh script comments:

```
#   CATALINA_OUT    (Optional) Full path to a file where stdout and stderr
#                   will be redirected.
#                   Default is $CATALINA_BASE/logs/catalina.out

$ export CATALINA_OUT=mylog.out
```

then run tomcat...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can this be added in catalina.properties file located in '\etc\tomcat'?

Comment: yes, if /etc/tomcat is read to build tomcat envirnonment. 
Else, this could be added in tomcat user's environment (e.g. .bashrc) or in startup script itself.

Comment: "Default is $CATALINA_BASE/logs/catalina.out" So even if I don't add the "$ export CATALINA_OUT=mylog.out" it should still by default write to "$CATALINA_BASE/logs/catalina.out". Am I right?

Comment: Can you please explain this one in detail - "Else, this could be added in tomcat user's environment (e.g. .bashrc) or in startup script itself".

Comment: Yes the defaults should be to log to "$CATALINA_BASE/logs/catalina.out".
Can you detail how exactly you start the tomcat server?